# I want to install AMD driver in ubuntu 15.10. but I cant

Tags: 15.10

I dont know how do that.. I search in internet but cant explain to install radeon-crimson-15.11-15.30.1025.zip . Anyone can help me.. I want to play dota but I cant

Comment: It may help a bit if you can explain which video card you have.

Comment: Related: [This old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/124292/37165) had asked on "What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?" and has multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

AMD now (28.11.2015) not support 15.10.
You have 3 options:
1. Install 15.04 or 14.04
2.  Enable "proposed" in Software & Upgrades (it contains update candidates to stable repository) and install all updates.
[proposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC4dH.png)
3. Wait till support will be added in main repository.